# Matching multiline text using regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

my input sample is:

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15">
<meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 15">
<link rel=File-List href="detailedFoot_files/filelist.xml">
```

What i want to do is i want to select the whole html tag and replace it with something. So i am using the regular expression

```
<html.*>
```

If i use this regular expression in a Mather.DOTALL manner, the whole text input is replaced.

I cant figure out how to do it. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this in Java or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

This regex seems to capture what you're looking for.

```
pattern = "\<html[^>]*>?(.*)"
```

**[Sample Here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%3chtml%5b%5e%3e%5d*%3e%3f(.*)&i=%3chtml+xmlns%3av%3d%22urn%3aschemas-microsoft-com%3avml%22%0d%0axmlns%3ao%3d%22urn%3aschemas-microsoft-com%3aoffice%3aoffice%22%0d%0axmlns%3aw%3d%22urn%3aschemas-microsoft-com%3aoffice%3aword%22%0d%0axmlns%3am%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2foffice%2f2004%2f12%2fomml%22%0d%0axmlns%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2fTR%2fREC-html40%22%3e%0d%0a%0d%0a%3chead%3e%0d%0a%3cmeta+http-equiv%3dContent-Type+content%3d%22text%2fhtml%3b+charset%3dwindows-1252%22%3e%0d%0a%3cmeta+name%3dProgId+content%3dWord.Document%3e%0d%0a%3cmeta+name%3dGenerator+content%3d%22Microsoft+Word+15%22%3e%0d%0a%3cmeta+name%3dOriginator+content%3d%22Microsoft+Word+15%22%3e%0d%0a%3clink+rel%3dFile-List+href%3d%22detailedFoot_files%2ffilelist.xml%22%3e)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace only the starting `html` tag the following will replace it:

```
String replaced = Pattern.compile("<html[^>]+>", Pattern.DOTALL)
    .matcher(input).replace("my replacement for html tag");
```

Comment: Multiline mode only affects the behavior of the anchors (`^` and `$`), so it will have no effect on this regex. Also, the OP want to match the HTML **tag**, not the whole document.